# Keep alive delays in Azure Iot Hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I have device connected to the iot-hub via the AMQP protocol. I'm looking how to change the timeout of the "keep alive delays" between device and hub. Is it possible? 
I've already tried to set timeouts from this C SDK site: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/doc/Iothub_sdk_options.md , but with no positive result so far.

Comment: Can you define your problem first? Is there some aggressive NAT layer in front of your device you that cuts off connectivity, something else? What's happening? What's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already found the solution. Here it is:

```
// https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-/blob/master/doc/Iothub_sdk_options.md
// note that not all option suits selected protocol     
const int KEEP_ALIVE_TIMEOUT_S = 30;
auto result = IoTHubDeviceClient_SetOption(deviceHandle, OPTION_C2D_KEEP_ALIVE_FREQ_SECS, &KEEP_ALIVE_TIMEOUT_S);
```